# Assembly missing by using ValueMember, DisplayMember and DataSource

Tags: c#, wpf, compilation, datasource, valuemember

I have a recurring error when using `ValueMember`, `DisplayMember` and `DataSource`.
This is a **compilation error** :

> CS1061  C# 'ComboBox' does not contain a definition for and no
>   accessible extension method accepting a first argument of type
>   'ComboBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?).

Here's the code-behind :

```
        Accueil.DataSource = dt;                       // <- Doesn't compile
        Accueil.DisplayMember = "Personnel_Accueil";   // <- Doesn't compile
        Accueil.ValueMember = "Personnel_Accueil";     // <- Doesn't compile
```

Why do i get this error ?
Thank you in advance,
Zancrew.

Comment: At which line do you have the compile time error, please?

Comment: .DataSource, .DisplayMember, .ValueMember are underlined in red and Visual Studio tells me that there is a compile time error at their line

Comment: What is the `type` of `Accueil`? If it's `ComboBox` then do you use `WinForms`, `WPF`, `Xamarin` or something else?

Comment: The type is ComboBox and i'm using WPF

Comment: Thanks for editing ! I take note so that my next messages will be clear !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The properties are named differently in WPF. Try this:

```
Accueil.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
Accueil.DisplayMemberPath = "Personnel_Accueil";
Accueil.SelectedValuePath = "Personnel_Accueil";
```